# Access violation writing location 0x00D00000

Tags: c

I am trying to write this simple program which reads multiple variables in one scanf function but an exception is thrown after I enter the input?

Edit: I used scanf initially but it causes an error saying it may be unsafe.

Exception thrown:

Exception thrown at 0x52DAB87C (ucrtbased.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00D00000

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender;
    float income;

    printf("Enter <name> <age> <gender> <income> :");
    scanf_s("%s %d %c %f", &name, &age, &gender, &income);

    printf("Name   : %s", name);
    printf("Age    : %d", age);
    printf("Gender : %c", gender);
    printf("Income : %.2f", income);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: not sure it fixes it: `&name` => `name`

Comment: `scanf_s("%s %d %c %f", &name, &age, &gender, &income);` --> `scanf_s("%19s %d %c %f",  name, 20, &age, &gender, 1, &income);`

Comment: I sense yet another code of (almost) correct scanf code being broken by user in response to bogus compiler message recommending `scanf` change to `scanf_s`

Comment: did you use scanf at the start? if so, I think _scanf("%s %d %c %f", name, &age, &gender, &income);_ should have work just fine

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What is the point of `%19s` if `scanf_s()` want `20` to know the size of the buffer ?

Comment: C does not support exceptions.

Comment: Tip: screen shots of text tends to attract down-votes.  Text is easier to search, cut and paste.

Comment: It isn't C throwing the exception, @Olaf, it is the operating system.

Comment: @Stargateur Please try out the difference in behavior actually.

Comment: @CodyGray: Too bad the screenshot is unreadable. That's why one should post text as text, not image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier to `scanf`/`scanf_s` expects a pointer to the first element of an array of char, i.e. a `char *`.  Instead, you're passing in the address of an array, in this case a `char (*)[20]`.  Those types are incompatible.  Passing the the wrong type for a format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of passing in `&name`, pass in `name`.  When passed to a function, an array decays to a pointer to the first element, so this is the proper type.

```
scanf_s("%19s %d %c %f", name, sizeof(name), &age, &gender, sizeof(gender), &income);
```

Also note the length specifier given, which limits the number of characters that can be read in so it doesn't try to write past the end of the array.